# Superflous leading dot in biblatex/numeric and beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, punctuation

The combination of `beamer` and `biblatex` with the `numeric` style leads to an undesired dot and space at the beginning of `@MISC` entries.

[image: extra dot]

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@MISC{www,
   title={TeX.SX},
   url={www.tex.stackexchange.com},
   urldate={2012-02-02},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\frame{Test \cite{www}}

\frame{\printbibliography}
\end{document}
```

Since this only happens with `beamer` and not `scrarticle` I guess it’s a `beamer` problem/imcompability. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: To anyone else with this issue: it has now been fixed in Beamer thanks to [Audrey's code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47582/2693), so if you still encounter it, you should update your packages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`.  You can temporarily fix it by adding

```
 \makeatletter
 \patchcmd{\abx@macro@title}{\blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct}{}{}
 \makeatother
```

right after `\begin{document}` in your file.

The same problem will arise with an empty `title` field in an entry. This is not so easily fixed at the moment, however.

(IMO this is safer than making your own local copy of `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`. In my experience, it's very easy to forget such local modifications and then be bitten down the road if the package is updated.)

Comment: This removes the first `\blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct` from `\abx@macro@title`. Re-executing the exact same `\patchcmd` would remove the second such instance as well. Joseph suggests removal of *both* in his answer. What would be the difference in using either or?

Comment: @Werner See my comment to Joseph's answer.

Comment: I don't think this will get the color of the unit punctuation following the label name right.

Comment: @Audrey, yes, I think you're right. I thought I checked that, but it has the same problem.

Answer (score 11):

In `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` you will find

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}
    {
      \apptocmd\blx@env@bibliography{\let\makelabel\beamer@biblabeltemplate}{}{}
      \pretocmd{\abx@macro@author}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}}{}{}
      \pretocmd{\abx@macro@editor}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}}{}{}
      \pretocmd{\abx@macro@title}{\blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct\newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}}{}{}
      \apptocmd{\abx@macro@title}{\blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct\newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}}{}{}
    }
    {}
}
```

The issue can be removed by using a modified version of this file which instead reads

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}
    {
      \apptocmd\blx@env@bibliography{\let\makelabel\beamer@biblabeltemplate}{}{}
      \pretocmd{\abx@macro@author}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}}{}{}
      \pretocmd{\abx@macro@editor}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}}{}{}
      \pretocmd{\abx@macro@title}{\newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}}{}{}
      \apptocmd{\abx@macro@title}{\blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct\newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}}{}{}
    }
    {}
}
```

Looking at this again, I'm not sure why that extra punctuation is there at all: I will update `beamer` with this fix.

Comment: I've changed the fix to repeat the original `\apptocmd`, otherwise the formatting of the title punctuation is incorrect.  This isn't the final solution, however, since if the `title` field is empty, spurious punctuation will arise again.

Comment: If I copy the second code block to my document it doesn’t seem to change anything but Alan’s solution worked. BTW: Where can I find `beamer`’s change history?

Comment: @Tobi No, as I said you would need to make a copy of `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` and change the code there, say in your local texmf tree. The change history is available from the BitBucket site: http://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/wiki/Home

Comment: Ohhh … I overread this, but why doesn’t it work with copying to my preamble?

Comment: @Tobi It doesn't work in the preamble because the code *appends* to the existing commands, it doesn't redefine them from scratch.  So if you put this in your preamble, you are now patching the (already) patched commands. So schematically you get `<new code><old code><rest of command>` which means that your `<newcode>` has no effect.  The reason my solution works, is that I used `patchcmd`, which replaces `<old code>` with `<new code>`.  It has to be after `\begin{document}` because the original patching was done within an `\AtBeginDocument{}` command.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Ahh, I didn’t think on the way `\pathcmd` works :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: I made the update and the dot disappeared but it seems like there is still a superfluous space at the beginning of the entry …

Comment: @Tobi The beamer labels you're using are wider than biblatex's label numbers. (They also sort of defeat the purpose of the numeric style, but I'm guessing you have some good reason for using them...) You can workaround this by using `\setlength{\labelnumberwidth}{<value>}` in your preamble.

Answer (score 11):

Patches to the low-level bibliography macros need to generate punctuation in some cases - otherwise the color of unit punctuation set outside the macros won't match the color of the preceding field. In this new hook the punctuation at the beginning of `title` is set if `labelname` is defined. The punctuation at the end is set if `title` is defined.

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}
    {\apptocmd\blx@env@bibliography{\let\makelabel\beamer@biblabeltemplate}{}{}
     \apptocmd{\abx@macro@begentry}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}}{}{}
     \pretocmd{\abx@macro@title}
       {\ifcsundef{abx@name@labelname}{}{\blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct}%
        \newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}}{}{}
     \apptocmd{\abx@macro@title}
       {\ifcsundef{abx@field@title}{}{\blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct}%
        \newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}}{}{}}
    {}}
```

I've also included a patch to `begentry`. Names from `editor` or `translator` form `labelname` when `author` undefined, but the original patches to the `author` and `editor` macros don't appear to handle this case properly.

The above hook should replace the one found in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`. Otherwise the original hook can be patched after `\begin{document}`. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{www,
   title={TeX.SX},
   url={www.tex.stackexchange.com},
   urldate={2012-02-02},}
@MISC{www2,
   url={www.tex.stackexchange.com},
   urldate={2012-02-02},}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
  \apptocmd{\abx@macro@begentry}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}}{}{}
  \patchcmd{\abx@macro@title}
    {\blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct\newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}}
    {\ifcsundef{abx@name@labelname}{}{\blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct}%
     \newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}}{}{}
  \patchcmd{\abx@macro@title}
    {\blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct\newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}}
    {\ifcsundef{abx@field@title}{}{\blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct}%
     \newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}}{}{}
\makeatother
\frame{Test \cite{www,companion,www2,moraux,gaonkar}}
\frame{\printbibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have merged this code into `beamer` (thanks to @AlanMunn). It will appear in the release version next time I update CTAN with a `beamer` release.